# Fill a rectangle in html5 canvas depending on a specific value

Tags: javascript

in my jsfiddle there is a simple rectangle filled in yellow color what i need is to update DrawRectangle in a way to fill the rectangle depending on a specific value if i give it 100 the whole rectangle should be filled if 15 than 15% of rectangle width should be filled only 
http://jsfiddle.net/J4HuQ/

```
var val = 100;
 DrawRectangle(val);
 function DrawRectangle(value){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(0,0,200,50);
  context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a simple math proportion `200:100 = x:15` = `(15*200)/100` = `30`

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6nKjN/

Comment: 200 is the maximum width, equal to 100%

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick

```
function fill(percent){
    //clear canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    context.beginPath();
    //change canvas.width to the max width of the rectangle if need be.
    context.rect(0,0,Math.round(canvas.width*(percent/100)),50);
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}
```

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/J4HuQ/1/